# Having to run Flutter Clean and remove framework everytime I switch building from Physical iOS and Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have a flutter Project I started a month ago. Yesterday my xcode automatically updated and began having this error

error: Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS Simulator. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

The only way I can make it work is to run the two commands below
$ flutter clean
$ rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework

so Now it runs smoothly on the physical device but if I want to run on the simulator
again I get a similar error without the word "Simulator" in it like this

error: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

To get it to work I have to run the two commands again.

Is this normal behaviour? I am sure the solution is simple? sorry I am new to flutter and iOS development. 
is there a way to have both frameworks in there for iOS Physical and for iOS Simulator so I don't have to clean and remove frameworks? Please let me know how exactly to add both. Steps would really be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: I experience exact the same issue, are you on xcode version: Version 11.4 (11E146) ?

Comment: Yes, Version 11.4 (11E146)

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 11.4 changed the way frameworks are linked and embedded. Flutter v1.15.3 and later will automatically migrate your Xcode project.

In the meantime, to fix it manually, follow the following instructions: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration

Comment: I tried that. It worked for on simulator but when I try on a physical device I get the error
Now my previous 2 commands dont work too :(

ios-deploy[94888:822429] [ !! ] Error 0xe800801c: No code signature found. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
Could not install build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on

Same error when Running from xcode

Unable to install "Runner"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388
--
No code signature found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388

Comment: still having this issue :( anyone figure this out?

Comment: This issue has returned with Flutter 1.20 :-/